# URL problem: www.sitename.com/blog and www.sitename.com/learn using same WP installation

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, site-url

I'm sure there has to be some way to make this with single wordpress instalation. Posts for "learn" page are tagged with "learn" and I built a custom template that has loop that prints only posts from that category. Also, posts on that "learn" page should have links like they are on separate WP installaton (www.sitename.com/learn/date-postname..) and same for blog (www.sitename.com/blog/date-postname..)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: well, simpler questions would be: How can I have all posts except "learn" category on one page and posts with "learn" category on another page? Also, how to do so that page with "learn" posts doesn't have sitename.com/blog/learn but sitename.com/learn URL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I exactly understand your problem, but it sounds like what you want to do could easily be accomplished using Custom post types: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types

This would basically allow you to have an entire segment just for 'learn' completely separated from your general posts/blog - you could even give 'learn' it's own styling by using `if ( 'learn' == get_post_type() )`

Comment: that's how I would do it. Just make sure you set `with_front` to `false` or you're have `example.com/blog/learn` You may also have to force the post permalink settings to include `/blog`

Comment: even if I have WP installed in sitename.com/blog folder and I need to have "learn" posts on sitename.com/learn?